# VmWare SQL Server Integration Services multi core performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, vmware

We run a SQL Server using SSIS. My ops department argue they won't raise the number of cores on the machine because its running on top of WmWare and they say adding more cores slows it down due to overhead of having to find the cores to run on.

My usecase is I have a SSIS job containing of multiple flows, sources, destinations, packages etc. that runs for anything from 10 to 8 hours. I would like to throw some more hardware at it so I asked them if we could up the core count to something like 32.

Price is not an issue. They simple claim that performance would not increase due to VmWare not working well with multiple cores.

I don't trust them. But I can't really counter them since i don't know anything about VmWare other then it sounds wrong. Sure multithreading has overhead etc. but a task running for 8 hours that can utilize multithreading and is not IO/RAM capped.

i do know alot of factors play into performance on a virtual enviorment and i can't really tell you much more then specs i know which are the following:

- SQL Server 2012
- Windows Server 2012 with 8 cores
- VmWare, don't know much else
- Runs in a big datacenter I or operations don't have access to the underlying 
  hardware or VmWare.

Comment: You should first understand the cause of the performance issue. Are cores actually maxing out? It's easy to write badly performing packages that take 10 hours. i.e. overuse of lookups, script tasks, SCD component etc. You might be able to rewrite your package to perform better. What is it actually doing?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I hear you Nick but its difficult to get the information. The SSIS packages moves alot of data and do alot of heavy transformation to it. We have people on with many years of SSIS development experience so we do understand the issues.

Comment: I can only say that the VMWare boffins should already see some saturation of cores in their logs if cores are the issue. I also have to throw in here: my many years of SSIS experience tells me that you should put logic in the database, not in the package. But it depends on the packages purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not wrong, but... there are a ton of variables that go into properly sizing a VM, so they may not be right either.

There are lots of metrics they can look at to check and see whether the system is starved for resources. Also, if they have access to something like vRealize Operations Manager, there are pre-made dashboards they can use to easily see what vROps recommends the VM's size should be. There are several other operations products out that do similar things too.

Here's some reading that can help you understand their position a little more as well as give you some things to follow up and ask them about:

- General Rightsizing Overview: http://virtual-red-dot.info/right-sizing-virtual-machines/
- SQL Server Performance Whitepaper: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the links!

Answer (score 0):

Your ops group needs a lot of help. VMWARE is a very, very mature product that has been around for many years and is the most widely used commercial product to virtualize machines. VMWARE knows how to use additional cores. Its like saying better to get a four cylinder instead of an eight cylinder because you will just confuse the engine.

Depending on what is causing the package to run for 8 hours it could not help much but it is very unlikely that it will run slower. It is easy to add the cores, run the package, and see if it runs faster. Please post the results. I would bet good money it will run faster but unless we see the package we won't know. You know that you can create multiple paths (containers) that execute in parallel (if appropriate) that will take advantage of the additional cores.